# Safari won't load on my G5; how can I get my bookmarks?

Tags: safari, powerpc, bookmarks, g5

I have a Mac, a Power PC G5 desktop, running MAC OS X 10.5.8, the last release made for this machine. I've been having a lot of problems lately with Safari; when I launch it, I get a spinning disc, and then Safari becomes unresponsive. My only option is to Force Quit.

Ideally, I'd like to resolve whatever is causing the issue.

Failing that, I'd like to somehow get to all my bookmarks. I just don't know enough about the inner workings of the computer to find where those are stored and how to access them.

Answer (score 1):

The bookmarks are stored in ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.html

Triaging the crashing app might be as simple as moving the entire preference folder and plist file to the desktop or might take more work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually bookmarks are in `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`

That file open up in Apple's **Property List Editor.app** not the easiest way to get things out.  (Tip option-click the disclose-triangle to open the entire tree view)

...so you are probably best off repairing what's wrong with Safari that's keeping it from starting.
Try force quitting it, then renaming (or backing & removing) the following:

- `~/Library/Caches/Safari` whole directory
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.RSS.plist`

If you are still wedged after that, fall back to trying to the generic mac debugging tips (repair permissions, etc)